# Create two nodes in the same package

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using catkin package with one node (cpp file).

I want to add one more node (cpp file) in the same package but I get this error during the compilation:

```
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'kinectueye'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(kinectueye) CMake Error at kinectueye/CMakeLists.txt:180 (add_executable):   add_executable cannot create target "kinectueye" because another target   with the same name already exists.  The existing target is an executable   created in source directory "/home/jros/catkin_ws/src/kinectueye". See   documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.
```

the package is called kinectueye and the kinectueye (the same name) is the executable of the first node.

How can I make one package with two nodes ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188145/create-two-nodes-in-the-same-package/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2014-07-29

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your second executable has to have a different name. Once you made sure that your two executables have different names, everything should work. For example:

```
add_executable(kinectueye_node src/main.cpp src/some_file.cpp src/another_file.cpp)
add_executable(kinectueye_configurator src/configurator.cpp)
```

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-07-29**:
Yes that's it. I forget to change kinectueye_node name.

**Comment by [isaiah A](https://answers.ros.org/users/109561/isaiah-a/) on 2022-08-29**:
Something I learnt the hard way is to always add a `target_link_libraries` line below the `add_executable` line for each executable.
In this case that would be:

```
add_executable(kinectueye_node src/main.cpp src/some_file.cpp src/another_file.cpp)
target_link_libraries(kinectueye_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_executable(kinectueye_configurator src/configurator.cpp)
target_link_libraries(kinectueye_configurator ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```